# How share ViewData between ViewComponent in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, viewdata, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have two ViewComponent and i want use ViewData or other technic for share some data between and then use this data in main view, but this is not the way, and ViewData per ViewComponent is null when rich to if condition for both ViewComponent.

```
public class OneViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Page page, Zone zone)
    {
        //some operation

        string text = "one";

        if(ViewData["data"] != null)
        {
            ViewData["data"] = ViewData["data"].ToString() + text;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["data"] = text;
        }

        return View();
    }
}

public class TwoViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Page page, Zone zone)
    {
        //some operation

        string text = "two";

        if(ViewData["data"] != null)
        {
            ViewData["data"] = ViewData["data"].ToString() + text;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["data"] = text;
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ViewData` is just like `ViewBag`. You use it only if you want to transfer data from Controller to View. For this I always prefer View Model.

For transferring data across component you have the following two options:

Using `TempData` dictionary instead of `ViewData` dictionary: you need to install the following package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures
```

In your `Startup` class, add this line

```
services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
```

to your `ConfigureServices` method. I use `CookieTempDataProvider` as impelmentation of `ITempDataProvider` but you can use `SessionStateTempDataProvider`.

To store data into `TempData` dictionary you use this code:

```
this.TempData["data"] = "my value";
```

To retrieve data from `TempData` you use this code:

```
var data = this.TempData["data"];
```

To use it in your component view:

```
@this.TempData["data"]
```

Using `HttpContext.Items` dictionary: there is no package to install. In your view component class, store your data in `HttpContext.Items` dictionary like this:

```
this.HttpContext.Items["data"] = "my value";
```

And access to the data stored by doing this:

```
var data = this.HttpContext.Items["data"];
```

In your component view, you can get the stored data by doing this:

```
@this.Context.Items["data"]
```

The difference between `TempData` and `HttpContext.Items`: the main difference between `HttpContext.Items` and `TempData` dictionary is:

- `HttpContext.Items` is cleared when the request ends.
- By default `TempData` is cleared when the data is read. To retain the data you need to explicitly call `TempData.Keep()`
- You can easily test your view compnent when you use `TempData` because it is an interface of type `ITempDataDictionary` which can be mocked without difficulty.

Comment: You can use HttpContext.Items to pass data from view-component to layout (where it is called Context.Items), which is what I needed. You CAN NOT use ViewData=ViewBag for that direction. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Imho this is an indicator that `ViewComponent`s are not suitable for your use case. You should use partial views instead.

Partial views are executed in the context of their parent'S view action and additionally you can pass a model to the partial, i.e.  a product from a product list.

```
@Html.Partial("PartialName", customViewData)
```

In your example above, you'd provide `"one"` and `"two"` as the partial's model parameter `@Html.Partial("PartialName", "one")`, `@Html.Partial("PartialName", "two")`

ViewComponents are more like reusable blocks of logic **and view** which act similarly to a controler + action. 
But unlike controller + action, the `ViewComponent` can be reused in multiple places.

ViewComponents should be self-sufficient and do not depend on data outside of them.

This also further more indicates that you are trying to move application related logic from an action to the view and that your data from your controller action isn't sufficiently prepared for the view to consume.

The controller's action has only 3 simple tasks: Validate user input, call the underlying application code (commonly called services) and prepare the service results for the view to consume it. That being said, a better solution may be, to use a viewmodel in your action (instead of `ViewData` which is untyped), prepare all the data you need and then let the view just display that data.

Comment: Not entirely true.. if you migration a RenderAction then Partial is not going to work. (Unless you can convert it to a View but most likely not) May as well just refactor the model on the ViewComponent to hold the data you need.. since the data can be anything on the Model (even passed on from the calling View)